# REST API Status Change

Tags: api, rest

I am designing a REST API.

I have a single resource that I want to be able to change the status of for different conditions e.g. the URI is:

**Applications/{application_id}/**

The possible status changes are to set the application to:

1. Cancelled
2. SignedOff
3. Hold

Each status change will require different information e.g. a reason for cancelled, a date for signedoff.

What would be a good looking URI to handle this? I had thought of

1. **POST: Applications/{application_id}/Cancel**
2. **POST: Applications/{application_id}/SignOff**
3. **POST: Applications/{application_id}/Hold**

but it doesnt seem right to me.

**EDIT:**

I should have mentioned that I was already planning
**POST: Applications/{application_id}** 
to update an existing application with a full set of application data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST: Applications/{application_id}?cancel=true
```

POST is used only for CREATE.  I think put will be better option.

Comment: Right. I use Taffy framework for my API and usually the POST/GET methods are used to determine if you are altering info or just getting it. Then you would post params to alter the info how you want to. Though if you follow your patter you might want to reverse your thinking. `Applicatins/cancel/id`. It's easier to read.

Comment: cancel, signoff, hold are verbs.  This is famous question though.  Like Orders can get cancelled or deleted.  How do you differentiate then?  The most suggested answer is use query params like cancel=true, signoff=true or hold=true.  When you do GET have a element <CANCEL>true</cancel> <signoff>false</signoff> like that.

Answer (score 2):

**I would stick with one url for all statuses** and have your Status object encapsulate all the different properties. These keeps your url from having words that look like actions and to be more restful.

```
POST: Applications/{application_id}/status

public class Status
{
   public string StatusType {get;set;}
   public string CancelReason {get;set;}
   public string SignOffDate {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution.